# Why my -webkit-background-clip: text ; is not working

Tags: html, css, django, webkit

I m tring to make an animation for text with gradient but my -webkit-background-clip:text; is not working please check whats the issue here:

```css
h2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-weight: 800;
    color: white;
    width: 10%;
    height: 20%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 400%;
    background: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(255,255,255,.9), rgba(255,30,80,1) 130%);
    animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="myname">
                <h2>Priyanshu Kumar</h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: You don't need it. `background-clip` is [supported almost universally](https://caniuse.com/?search=background-clip) without a prefix. Take it out and it will work.

Comment: not working bro

Comment: works for me bro https://codepen.io/selfagency/pen/xxqowma

Comment: you need to put the background before the background-clip

Comment: @selfagency the -webkit- is still needed from chrome (test your code in chrome and it won't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Temani Afif your answer worked, thanks.

I had put my background before background-clip and it worked for me.